# error: a parameter list without types is only allowed in a function definition

Tags: c, function, cs50

I'm learning how to create and use functions. My code doesn't compile but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool tri (double x, double y, double z);

int main(void)
{
    double x = get_double("Give:");
    double y = get_double("Another:");
    double z = get_double("Now:");

    bool tri (x, y, z);
}

bool tri (double x, double y, double z)
{
    if (x<1 || y<1 || z<1)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (x+y > z && y+z > x && z+x > y)
    {
        return true;
    }

    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I try to compile this code, I get the following error:

```
error: a parameter list without types is only allowed in a function definition
bool tri (x, y, z);
          ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Your problem

What you wrote is recognized by your compiler as a [*function prototype*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype). So it tells you that you should have something like this, with types:

```
bool tri(double x, double y, double z);
```

### Solution

Here, you don't want a function prototype, instead, you want to *call* your function. **You don't need to specify the return type when calling a function.**

So simply do this:

```
tri(x, y, z);
```

...instead of `bool tri(x, y, z);`.

Comment: Perfect. I understand it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A couple of small changes are suggested below - most notably you put the return value of the function into a `bool` called `val` declared at the top and then print out at the end the values of `x,y,z` and `val` which is the true or false returned by your function.

Note you need to use the function you have written and something that returns a values which is why you need something like `val = tri (x, y, z);` to capture the returned value, which you can then print out...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool tri (double x, double y, double z);

int main(void)
{
    bool val;
    double x = get_double("Give:");
    double y = get_double("Another:");
    double z = get_double("Now:");

    val = tri (x, y, z);
    printf("x=%g, y=%g, z=%g\n",x,y,z);
    printf("%s", val ? "true" : "false");
    return 0;
}

bool tri (double x, double y, double z)
{
    if (x<1 || y<1 || z<1)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (x+y > z && y+z > x && z+x > y)
    {
        return true;
    }

    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I realise I don't understand the usage of bool very well. I had no idea I could declare it like you declare an integer. Thank you so much!

Comment: @callmeanythingyouwant - no problem, but note you can only use `bool` because you include the `stdbool.h` header at the top of your code.