# Solved the problem of "a parameter list without types is only allowed in a function definition" error

Tags: c

I am a beginner in program C, and I have a problem when running the code for student management program on VScode which I cannot run the displayStudent and searchstudentbyID functions and I cannot find out what causes these errors

Here is my programming code (p/s: as i am a vietnamese student, so some of the names in printfs and in comments section are in vietnamese).

```
//Seach by id 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student //ten cau truc
{
    int id;
    char name[50];
    float marks;
};
struct student *st;

int main(){
    int i,n;
    printf("\nBan muon luu bao nhieu sv: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    //cap phat bo nho dong cho struct
    st = (struct student*)malloc(n*sizeof(struct student));
   
    for(i =0; i< n; i++){
        //input information
        printf("\nEnter student information ");
        printf("\n--------------------------");
       
        printf("\nStudent id: ");
        scanf("%d",&(st+i)->id);//scanf("%d",&st[i].id);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nStudent name:");
        scanf("%s",&(st+i)->name);
       
        printf("\nStudent Marks: ");
        scanf("%f",&(st+i)->marks);
    }
}
    searchStudentById(st,n);
    displayStudent(st,n);
void displayStudent(struct student *st, int n){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("\nId: %d, name: %s, Marks: %f",(st+i)->id, (st+i)->name, (st+i)->marks );
    }
}
void searchStudentById(struct student *st, int n){
    int search;
    int i;
    printf("\nNhap id sv can tim: ");
    scanf("%d",&search);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        if((st+i)->id==search){
            printf("\nId: %d, name: %s, Marks: %f",(st+i)->id, (st+i)->name, (st+i)->marks );
        } 
    }
}
```

And here is the errors

```
tempCodeRunnerFile.c:35:5: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
    searchStudentById(st,n);
    ^
tempCodeRunnerFile.c:35:23: error: a parameter list without types is only allowed in a function definition
    searchStudentById(st,n);
                      ^
tempCodeRunnerFile.c:36:5: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
    displayStudent(st,n);
    ^
tempCodeRunnerFile.c:36:20: error: a parameter list without types is only allowed in a function definition
    displayStudent(st,n);
                   ^
3 warnings and 2 errors generated.
```

Comment: You need to declare prototypes for those functions before they are called for the first time, or move the definitions above the main function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: a parameter list without types is only allowed in a function definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49571922/error-a-parameter-list-without-types-is-only-allowed-in-a-function-definition)

Comment: The problem is that these ... `searchStudentById(st,n); displayStudent(st,n);` ... appear after the closing brace of `main()`.  Function calls can appear only inside functions, so the compiler is trying to interpret those as function declarations instead.  Moving them inside `main()` should make those particular errors go away, but I have not analyzed the program well enough to opine on whether it will then work correctly.

Comment: What is the purpose of the lines `searchStudentById(st,n);` and `displayStudent(st,n);`? Are these intended as function declarations? In this case move these to before the `main` function and add the data types. Or function calls? Then move them into a function. Please [edit] your question to provide this information, don't use comments for this purpose.